# Process or not to Process?

Tags: vhdl

I have the below code in VHDL that I use in a project. I have been using a Process within the architecture and wanted to know if there were any other means which I'm sure there are of accomplishing the same goal.. in essence to take one number compare it to another and if there is a difference of +/- 2 reflect this in the output. I am using the following:

```
LIBRARY IEEE;
USE IEEE.std_logic_1164.all, IEEE.std_logic_arith.all, IEEE.std_logic_signed;

ENTITY thermo IS
PORT (
        CLK         : in std_logic;
        Tset, Tact  : in std_logic_vector (6 DOWNTO 0);
        Heaton      : out std_logic
        );
END ENTITY thermo;

ARCHITECTURE behavioral OF thermo IS
SIGNAL TsetINT, TactINT : integer RANGE 63 Downto -64; --INT range so no 32bit usage
BEGIN
Heat_on_off: PROCESS
    VARIABLE ONOFF: std_logic;
        BEGIN
        TsetINT <= conv_integer (signed (Tset));--converts vector to Int
        TactINT <= conv_integer (signed (Tact));--converts vector to Int
        --If you read this why is it conv_integer not to_integer?? thx
        ONOFF := '0'; --so variable does not hang on start
            WAIT UNTIL CLK'EVENT and CLK = '1';
                IF TactINT <= (TsetINT - 2) then
                    ONOFF := '1';
                ELSIF TactINT >= (TsetINT + 2) then
                    ONOFF := '0';
                END IF;
                Heaton <= ONOFF;
END PROCESS;
END ARCHITECTURE behavioral;
```

I'm just after a comparison really and to know if there are any better ways of doing what I have already done.

Comment: 'after a comparison' to what? The subjective value 'better' may need a bit of amplification,  'better ways' in what sense? You could note that all concurrent statements are elaborated into one or more processes potentially encapsulated in block statements providing hierarchy. That leaves form but you're toggling one bit with two exclusive conditions. What's left, style?

Comment: The question is not wether _if there are any better ways of doing what I have already done_. I don't think so, that the code has the intended behaviour because the flip-flop is reset if not `TactINT <= (TsetINT-2)` at the rising clock-edge. Get your code right before asking for a code review. Please note, that there is also another [specialized forum for reviews on StackExchange](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 2):

Why convert Tact and Tset to an integer?

Why have the variable ONOFF?  The variable initialization appears to remove any sense of hysteresis, is that what you intended?   Based on your other code, I bet not.  I recommend that you assign directly to the signal Heaton instead of using the variable ONOFF.

If I were to create TsetINT and TactINt, these would be good candidates to be variables.  However, there is no need to do the integer conversion as you can simply do the following:

```
  if signed(Tact) <= signed(Tset) - 2 then 
    ...
  elsif signed(Tact) >= signed(Tset) + 2 then
```

Please use numeric_std.  Please ask your professor why they are teaching you old methodologies that are not current industry practice.  Numeric_std is an IEEE standard and is updated with the standard, std_logic_arith is not an IEEE standard.

```
use ieee.numeric_std.all ;
```

Comment: @DanielJHall  Look up Socratic method.   While we try to help, we don't do your homework.  You did ask if there were better ways.  I would start by simulating your design and see if Tact ever reaches Tset.  It won't.  Re-read my paragraph on ONOFF and Good Luck.

Answer (score 1):

In response to Jim's comment I wrote a simple thermal model test bench to test your design.

I only changed your design to use package numeric_std instead of the Synopsys packages. The rest is just prettifying and eliminating comments not germane to the question of whether or not Tact ever reaches Tset.

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity thermo is
    port (
        CLK:          in  std_logic;
        Tset, Tact:   in  std_logic_vector (6 downto 0);
        Heaton:       out std_logic
    );
end entity thermo;

architecture behavioral of thermo is
    signal TsetINT, TactINT:  integer range 63 downto -64;
begin

HEAT_ON_OFF: 
    process
        variable ONOFF: std_logic;
    begin
        TsetINT <= to_integer (signed (Tset));  -- package numeric_std
        TactINT <= to_integer (signed (Tact));  -- instead of conv_integer

        ONOFF := '0'; -- AT ISSUE -- so variable does not hang on start

        wait until CLK'event and CLK = '1';

        if TactINT <= TsetINT - 2 then  -- operator precedence needs no parens
            ONOFF := '1'; 
        elsif TactINT >= TsetINT + 2 then
            ONOFF := '0';
        end if;

        Heaton <= ONOFF;

    end process;

end architecture behavioral;
```

You have a comment in your process asking why conv_integer was required instead of to_integer. That prompted the change.

I removed superfluous parentheses based on operator order precedence (adding operators being higher precedence than relational operators), notice Jim's answer did the same.

So the simple model thermal model runs with a clock set to a 1 second period, and has two coefficients, relating to the temperature increase when `Heaton` is '1' or not.  I arbitrarily set the heating up coefficient to 1 every 4 clocks, and the temperature decay coefficient to 1 every 10 clocks. Also set the ambient temperature (tout) to 10 and tset to 22.  The numbers selected are severe to keep the model run time short enhancing portability without relying on setting a simulator resolution limit.

The thermal model  was implemented using fixed signed arithmetic without using fixed_generic_pkg, allowing portability to -1993 tools without math packages and includes a fractional part, responsible for the different widths of Heaton true after reaching normal operating temperature. The model could just as easily have been implemented with two different precursor counters used to tell when to increment or decrement Tact.

Using REAL types is possible, not desirable because converting REAL to INTEGER (then to SIGNED) isn't portable (IEEE Std 1076-2008 Annex D).

The idea here is to demonstrate the lack of hysteresis and demonstrate the model doesn't reach Tset:

[image: thermo_test.png no hysteresis]

The lack of hitting Tset (22 + 2) is based on the lack of hysteresis. Hysteresis is desirable for reducing the number of heat on and off cycles The idea is once you start the heater you leave in on for a while, and once you stop it you want to leave it off for a while too.

Using Jim's modification:

```
-- signal TsetINT, TactINT:  integer range 63 downto -64;
```

begin

HEAT_ON_OFF: 
    process (CLK)
    begin

```
    if rising_edge(CLK) then
        if signed(Tact) <= signed(Tset) - 2 then 
            Heaton <= '1';
        elsif signed(Tact) >= signed(Tset) + 2 then
            Heaton <= '0';
        end if;
    end if;
end process;
```

gives us longer Heaton on and off cycles, decreasing how many times the heater starts and stops:

[image: thermo_test_w_hys.png]

And actually allows us to see the temperature reach Tset + 2 as well as Tset - 2. where these thresholds provide the hysteresis which is characterized as a minimum on or minimum off time, depending on the efficiency of the heater and heat loss rate when the heater is off.

So what changed in the execution of the thermo model process? Look at the difference in the synthesis results for the two versions.

Comment: Thanks for the effort in trying to provide an understandable answer to a layman. I'll get back to you